# Как выровнять текст с картинкой в блоке по середине?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

Несмотря на постановку вопроса, цель немного другая. Как вы видите на картинке, img выровнялась вместе с текстом, в то время как мне нужно, чтобы текст выравнивался по центру блока, а картинка была слева от него.

```css
:root {
  --dark-blue: #34495e;
  --green: #27ae60;
  --shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
}

.categories {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(382px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.category {
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  border: 3px solid var(--green);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 85px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.category h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  color: var(--green);
  /*margin-left: 5%;*/
}

.category p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: var(--green);
  margin: 24px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*width: 70%; */
}

.category img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <button class="category">
    <img src="svg/fashion.svg" alt="">
    <h1>Одежда</h1>
  </button>
  <button class="category">
    <img src="svg/dish.svg" alt="">
    <h1>Хозтовары</h1>
  </button>
  <button class="category">
    <img src="svg/armchair.svg" alt="">
    <p>Товары для дома</p>
  </button>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте смещение для изображения со значением его ширины через `margin-left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше выбрать такой вариант! Ваша картинка точно будет прикреплена к тексту и никуда от него не денется!

```css
:root {
 --dark-blue: #34495e;
 --green: #27ae60;
 --shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
}

.categories {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(382px, 1fr));
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 margin: 0 20px;
}

.category {
 display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100px;
}

h1::before{
 content: url(https://png.icons8.com/android/64/000000/stripe.png);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: -70px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
h1{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <button class="category">
   <h1>Одежда</h1>
  </button>
  <button class="category">
   <h1>Хозтовары</h1>
  </button>
  <button class="category">
   <h1>Товары для дома</h1>
  </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: До тех пор, пока не доберется до края кнопки. Если уж использовать css для прописывания каждой иконки, куда проще использовать `padding`, `margin` и `background`

Comment: А еще лучше добавить после текста еще одну картинку с opacity: 0; а родителю дать display: flex; justify-content center; Это будет надежнее всего!

Comment: Текст будет по середине, а картинки по две стороны от него и лишь одна будет видна. а еще лучше просто блок, что бы не грузить картинкой!

Comment: Это хорошо, но что делать с если у меня svg ? В content нельзя указать размеры картинки...

Comment: Если svg то можно добавить после текста еще одну картинку с opacity: 0; а родителю дать display: flex; justify-content center; То есть получится картинка, текст, картинка. Все она выровняются по центру, правую спрятать и дело в шляпе. И не важно svg там или base64...

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте смещение для изображения со значением его ширины через `margin-left`

```css
:root {
 --dark-blue: #34495e;
 --green: #27ae60;
 --shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
}

.categories {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(382px, 1fr));
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 margin: 0 20px;
}

.category {
 background: var(--dark-blue);
 border: 3px solid var(--green);
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 85px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.category h1 {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 2.3em;
 color: var(--green);
 /*margin-left: 5%;*/
}

.category p {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 1.9em;
 color: var(--green);
 margin: 24px 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 /*width: 70%; */
}


.category img {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle; 
    min-width: 50px; 
    min-height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px; 
    max-height: 50px;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <button class="category">
   <img src="svg/fashion.svg" alt="">
   <h1>Одежда</h1>
  </button>
  <button class="category">
   <img src="svg/dish.svg" alt="">
   <h1>Хозтовары</h1>
  </button>
  <button class="category">
   <img src="svg/armchair.svg" alt="">
   <p>Товары для дома</p>
  </button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо такой! Он намного больше приближен к вашему!

```css
:root {
 --dark-blue: #34495e;
 --green: #27ae60;
 --shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
}

.categories {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(382px, 1fr));
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 margin: 0 20px;
}

.category {
 background: var(--dark-blue);
 border: 3px solid var(--green);
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 85px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.category h1 {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 2.3em;
 color: var(--green);
 /*margin-left: 5%;*/
}

.category p {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 1.9em;
 color: var(--green);
 margin: 24px 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 /*width: 70%; */
}


.category img {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle; 
    min-width: 50px; 
    min-height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px; 
    max-height: 50px;
    margin-right: 3%;
}

.main{
  position: relative;
}
.main img{
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <button class="category">
   <div class='main'>
     <img src="https://png.icons8.com/android/64/000000/stripe.png" alt="">
   <h1>Одежда</h1>
   </div>
  </button>
  <button class="category">
   <div class='main'>
     <img src="https://png.icons8.com/android/64/000000/stripe.png" alt="">
   <h1>Хозтовары</h1>
   </div>
  </button>
  <button class="category">
   <div class="main">
     <img src="https://png.icons8.com/android/64/000000/stripe.png" alt="">
   <p>Товары для дома</p>
   </div>
  </button>
 </div>
```